# MongoDb shell doesn't understand JavaScript Map's?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

When I'm running the following JavaScript script in MongoDb Shell (version 4.2), it says it doesn't understand the .set function?

```
const xxx = new Map();

print (xxx instanceof Map); // Output below displays "true"

xxx.set('bar', 'foo');

print('**************');
```

with the following error:

```
MongoDB shell version v4.2.18
connecting to: mongodb://mongodb.data:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("b1152dd2-02a2-4624-ae28-f3e4f34785b8") }
MongoDB server version: 4.2.18
true
2022-04-03T12:38:44.381+0000 E  QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: TypeError: xxx.set is not a function :
@run-update.js:5:1
2022-04-03T12:38:44.382+0000 F  -        [main] failed to load: run-update.js
2022-04-03T12:38:44.382+0000 E  -        [main] exiting with code -3
root@1548dcbfb906:/src/scripts#
```

Surely MongoDB shell can handle JavaScript Maps, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MongoDB shell implements its own version of the `Map` type, rather than the "ES6" Map type. The MongoDB type uses `put` instead of `set` to add elements to the map, this is why MongoDB returns an error when trying to use `set`.
The issue has been reported in the [MongoDB issues tracker](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-46243) .

Comment: Wow! i .. just .. don't know ... what to say. But thank you for pointing this out. Cheers!